# Why cannot print a list like this in python?

Tags: python, list, printing

**EDIT: after comments**

Say I have list of class objects

```
lis = [Cls(i*1.0) for i in range(1,3,1)]
```

and the `__str__` and `__repr__` functions are also equipped.

```
class Cls:
    def __init__(self:object, inp:float)->None:
        self._inp = inp
   
    def __str__(self):
        return f'Cls_str: r={self._inp}'

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Cls_repr: r={self._inp}'

    @property
    def inp(self):
        return self._inp

    @inp.setter
    def inp(self,value:float=0):
        self._inp=float(value)

    @inp.deleter
    def inp(self)->inp.deleter:
        del self._inp
```

then instead of `for i in range(2,len(lis),1): print(lis[i])`, it is expected to print like this. But it failed...

```
    print(lis[i]) for i in range(2,len(lis),1) # either
    print(lis[i] for i in range(2,len(lis),1))
```

Comment: Why not `for i in range(2,len(list),1):print(list[i])`?

Comment: You can do `print(lst)` to print the whole list or `for item in lst: print(item)` to print one item at a time. Your first line `print(list[i]) for i in range(2,len(list),1)` is incorrect syntax, and the second one `print(list[i] for i in range(2,len(list),1))` will print the generator `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x015AF830>` defined by the generator expression `list[i] for i in range(2,len(list),1)`

Comment: And don't use `list` as name, it's a built-in

Comment: For sake of completeness this `[print(item) for item in lst]` will also work, but it's an abuse of list comprehension for side effects (one-liner). Don't do that.

Comment: Note that the explicit step 1 in `range()` is just a variant copy from original code for convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try unpacking using `*`:**

```
print(*lst[2:],sep='\n')
```

**OR**

```
print(*(list[i] for i in range(2,len(list),1),sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can print is like this:

```
for i in range(2,len(list),1):
    print(list[i])
```

or if that doesn't suits you, you can print it like this:

```
[print(list[i]) for i in range(2,len(list),1)]
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit step of `1`.  Normally this is only specified when it is *not* a constant `1`.

Comment: Don't abuse list_comprehension for side effects

Comment: I don't need it of course, I just copypasted that code

Comment: @buran I understand it, I just answer the question 'why it's not printed'

Comment: @buran in this iterable `lst = [someobj, someobj1, someobj2]` how to iterate it for printing each item without list comprehension but in one line?

Comment: Thought not recommended to abuse list comprehension, the LIST extension function is working for this purpose,  ````[print(list[i]) for i in range(2,len(list),1)]```` but  will print ````[None, None, None]```` which is not expected.

Comment: @DmitriyNeledva, one-liner is not a must. readability counts. As suggested by Bibhav `print(*lst, sep='\n')` will work, but in my opinion explicit loop would be preferable in most cases.

Comment: @MathArt, if you have `[print(item) for item in lst]` it will print each item and produce a list of `[None, None, None]`, but it is thrown-way and not printed

Comment: That's why it is not the good way to use list extension for printing.